# Mount a partition to two mount points

Tags: linux, mount, partition, hard-drive

I have a partition called sda4.

And I want to store the mysql data and xml files on that partition because the partition which mysql and domain are installed has little space.

So I'm planning to have two subfolders under the sda4, one for mysql and one for xml.
Then I want to mount the subfolders respectively like this:

```
mount -t auto /dev/sda4/mysql /var/lib/mysql

mount -t auto /dev/sda4/xml /home/user/domain/public_html/xml
```

Is my plan doable? Can mount a partition to two mount points?

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/a/128519/142948 - you can use `mount --bind`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't.

Longer answer: mount `/dev/sda4` on one mount point, and do a soft link from the other mount point.  Or mount it on a third, application-neutral point, and soft link from both the application points.

**Edit**: re a tutorial, try:

```
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
ln -s /mnt/mysql /var/lib/mysql
ln -s /mnt/xml /home/user/domain/public_html/xml
```

**NB**: it is necessary that neither `/var/lib/mysql` or `/home/user/domain/public_html/xml` exist, or the `ln -s` will do something predictable but unexpected.

**Edit 2**: it's OK that that stuff exists, you'll need to move it to one side.  Having mounted `/dev/sda4` on `/mnt` (see above), try

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.mark
mv /home/user/domain/public_html/xml /home/user/domain/public_html/xml.mark
```

(do the soft links, as above)

```
mv /var/lib/mysql.mark/* /var/lib/mysql
mv /home/user/domain/public_html/xml.mark/* /home/user/domain/public_html/xml
```

which should leave you with two empty `.mark` directories that can now be removed.  **Do not do this while the applications are running!**

Comment: can you point me to a tutorial that have steps to accomplished your suggestion? Not familiar with soft links. Thanks.

Comment: just a follow up do i need to create the subfolders(mysql and xml) under mnt?

Comment: Assuming that `/dev/sda4` contains a brand-new, empty filesystem, then yes, you will need to create those subdirectories, and permission them appropriately.  And if I may presume, because you're new on SF (welcome!), when you're happy with the answer to a question, local etiquette is that you accept that answer by clicking on the "tick" outline, which drives the reputation system for both you and the author of the answer.  I apologise if you already know this.

Comment: the problem now is `/var/lib/mysql` and `/home/user/domain/public_html/xml` are existing because it is there upon installation of mysql and directadmin

Comment: anoher thing I did was mount as bind `mount --bind /location/one /alias/mountpoint2`