# Does soft link affects xml parsing and database process

Tags: linux, partition, hard-drive, symbolic-link, symlink

I have a php code that does an xml parsing and inserts data into the mysql database.
The code can process one xml file in an average of 18 minutes.
Since I will be having lots of xml files and database space, 
I have configured the xml files and mysql data to be stored in different partition with a large space.
I used soft link in the configuration. I'm not familiar with soft links. [Good someone help me here with the configurations](https://serverfault.com/questions/451223/mount-a-partition-to-two-mount-points).

But after changing the configurations, I notice that php code will take about 35 minutes in average to finish processing. I wonder if it is because of the soft links to another partition?
The xml files are of the same size and there are no changes on any configurations on the server except on the soft links.
Is there a drawback in terms of processing speed on using soft links? Or is there another alternative if it has drawbacks?

The soft links configurations is working fine. I just want to lessen the processing speed. I only suspect the difference in processing is caused by the soft links. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Soft links can't make your XML processing that much slower.

Where did the files live when you tested and got 18 minutes processing time?

Perhaps the ***new disk*** the files live now **is** just **slower**?

You should try configuring your application to access the files directly from the place they are mounted (a soft link is just an 'alias' or short cut to another location).

I think you will find our that if you configure your scripts to use /mnt/xml instead of the softlink at /home/user/domain/public_html/xml (thus bypassing the soft link) you will still get the same performance...

Comment: files live on the same partition when the processing time is 18 minutes.